# 2 nexus docker private

Tags: docker, nexus

I have below requirements on nexus docker repo

1. Need to create 2 nexus docker repository with role seperation.
2. Both should listen to one port say same as nexus one 8081
3. developer 1 should be able push and pull to nexus docker 1 and developer 2 should access docker .

Is it possible in nexus 3?

Thanks
Siddu

Answer (score 1):

Sadly to allow HTTP connection to repository you must expose repository in nexus via TCP port - it means that if you want to have 2 repositories in one nexus you need to expose them on different ports for example 8082 and 8083.

You can for example use reverse proxy like nginx to make different subdomains to allow access to your repositories like:

```
registry1.domain.net -> nexus.domain.net:8082
registry2.domain.net -> nexus.domain.net:8083
```

Creating roles scenarios is possible in nexus3 - you can restrict access to only pull images or only push or both.

So developers will use

```
docker login registry1.domain.net
docker login registry2.domain.net
```

To receive different access to different registries.